# "No route found for GET" on custom REST resource when posting

Tags: authentication-authorization, page-controller

I'm seeing really weird behavior.  I've created a custom REST resource at the route  `/user/login-special`.

This is a passwordless login resource, so I pass the `mail` address and then get a response that says `Login email was sent!`

However, when I POST to the `https://abc-xyz-123.us-3.platformsh.site/user/login-special?_format=json`, I get the error:

```
{
    "message": "No route found for \"GET https://www.abc-xyz-123.us-3.platformsh.site/user/login-special?_format=json\" (from \"https://abc-xyz-123.us-3.platformsh.site/user/login-special?_format=json\")"
}
```

The route definitely exists... what is going on?  And why is it saying GET when I used POST?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the error carefully.

You POSTed to `https://abc-xyz-123.us-3.platformsh.site/user/login-special?_format=json`, but it is returning https://**www**-- you're getting redirected.

So the solution is to POST to `https://www.abc-xyz-123.us-3.platformsh.site/user/login-special?_format=json` and everything works as expected.

This might be obvious to most people, but I wasted a lot of time debugging this today, so I'm posting it here in case anyone else makes the same mistake in the future.